# Nutch Parser Plugin Collect Contact Information

Tags: plugins, nutch

I am working on a project that need to identify contact points on company's website and used for the purpose of enhancing security.

Right now, I managed to use Apache Nutch to crawl several rounds of sites. The next step will be to parse the HTML pages and locate where the contact information is. In this case, I am only interested in email addresses and phone numbers....

Here is what I am planning to do, we can write a map reduce jobs to parse HTML file and use things like regular expression in combo with Jsoup/Beautifulsoup HTML parsers to find the regular expression.

However, I am wondering is there any parser plugin that has already been implemented and maybe tested used for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to write a custom map reduce job. Just implement a bespoke HTMLParseFilter which will give you a DOM to run XPath expressions on + the text of the document if you want regular expressions.

Having worked on something similar for a customer a few years ago, I found that there were many pages implementing schema.org. You could write a custom HTMLParse filter with Xpath to extract normalised info from the microdata. You can look at the [microdata parser](https://github.com/PopSugar/storm-crawler-extensions/tree/master/microdata-parser) which is for StormCrawler as a an example of how to leverage Apache Any23 to extract microdata.

If you want a more NLP-intensive method, you could use [Behemoth](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/behemoth) to process Nutch segments with tools such as Apache UIMA or GATE.

HTH